# Scherzer Piccolo Trumpet

Tags: discussion

I see you have used my image of a Scherzer Piccolo trumpet without asking my permission. Your comments please. Trevor Jones Brass & Woodwind Ltd. Bristol

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could please edit your question to indicate where the picture is being used, then someone will be able to flag your post for a moderator to take appropriate action.

Comment: Please also note that,  as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114919/154510, we cannot necessarily take down your copyrighted works on your behalf (though we do tend to do so in clear cut cases).  Please file a formal DMCA takedown notice with Stack Exchange if you want the official process to be followed.

Comment: Are you perhaps unaware that images are posted by random users, not the owners of the site?  And that failure to attribute does not in itself constitute unlawful use? Plagiarism may have happened here, but certainly Fair Use covers a photo used as an example.

Answer (score 2):

as @topo commented, please let us know where. Our site policy is to always use image attribution so we encourage all users to do this, but we can't help without knowing which picture you are referring to.

Comment: Is this not better as a comment?

Comment: Perhaps: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38021/which-finger-should-i-use-for-the-fourth-valve-of-a-piccolo-trumpet which seems to match: http://www.trevorjonesltd.co.uk/Scherzer_Piccolo_Trumpet.htm

Comment: Thanks Todd - I'll try and sort it when I get back to a desktop machine.

Comment: But has the OP produced any evidence that he's the copyright holder on that image?

Comment: No, so I have just referenced the source